# Views Template Field Rendering

Tags: 7, views

I have a view which is a block on a page and I want to style the view. I tried using the rewrite output however I ran into a problem with it removing the `style=""` tag. So I had to resort to a .tpl.php to modify the display as I please.

Currently I am using

```
$d = $view->result;

    // Loop through it
    foreach($d as $r) {
        // Get values
        $position = $r->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_position['und']['0']['value'];

        $name = $r->_field_data['nid']['entity']->title;

        $image = file_create_url($r->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_picture['und']['0']['uri']);

        $path = drupal_lookup_path('alias',"node/".$r->nid);

        print "<div class='e'><a href='/".$path."' class='colorbox-load'><div class='tb' style='background-image:url(".$image.");'></div></a><strong>".$name."</strong><span>".$position."</span></div>";
    }
```

And as you see this is extremely ugly and I am dependent on 'und' not changing... which it does.

Is there another way to get the view field data besides having to go through the array and find it? I tried render() and that didn't work. I also tried using `entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $view);` and that didn't work (the fields where not attached to the array).

I can't figure out how to do it without the hacking code... Help!

Comment: I neither understand what you are trying to accomplish, nor what the problem is you encounter.

Comment: I'm trying to get the values from the view. I am using a very hacky code which I was told not to use http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There did not appear to be any way to do this easier, so I did it manually/hacky.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Incase you haven't noticed, it's my own question and I asked it 16 months ago. I am answering the question, which was "is there a better way" the answer is "no"